# Marshalling OpenSsl SSL_ctrl function to C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, openssl, marshalling

I have a problem with marshalling SSL_ctrl func from OpenSsl 1.0.2 beta.

This func is

```
long  SSL_ctrl(SSL *ctx, int cmd, long larg, void *parg);
```

I'm trying to marshal it as

```
[DllImport(SSLDLLNAME, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern long SSL_ctrl(IntPtr /* SSL* */ ssl,
                               int cmd,
                               long larg,
                               IntPtr parg);
```

*I've enabled native code debugging in my Visual Studio.*

The problem is the **last argument**.

I've tried to call that func with different pointers (non zero) but result is always same: 
native code accepts parg, but parg is equal to `0x0`.

I've tried to pass strings (got pointer by calling `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(serverName)),`
tried to pass some generated non-zero pointer, but the result is always same. parg is 0x0 in the native code.

Could you please help me with that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`long` in C# is the equivalent of `int64_t` in C. The size of `long` in C depends on implementation, and with most Win32 implementations it is equivalent to `int32_t`. Therefore, the value `parg` you observe in your unmanaged code is the value of upper 32 bits of `larg` in your managed code.

In general, it is not advisable to use implementation-dependent types in C interoperability interfaces.

Comment: I've tried to marshal it as int SSL_ctrl... But result is same.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've just finally understood what did you mean. Yes, my 32 bits where under larg. Solved. Thanks again